# Using the RouteOnAttribute processor to route on ListenSyslog processors, written attribute 'syslog.hostname'

Tags: apache-nifi

I've successfully created a flow that uses the processors ListenSyslog and PutFile to capture syslog messages and write them to a file on disk.

I would however like to be able to use the RouteOnAttribute processor to route these incoming syslog messages using the source IP of the syslog message. The ListenSyslog processor info page lists that it writes attributes "syslog.hostname - The hostname or IP address of the Syslog message" I want to use this attribute in my RouteOnAttribute processor.

I'am unclear on how to access the written attributes of the ListenSyslog processor from within the RouteOnAttribute processor configuration properties to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every attribut  can be access with this syntax : `${my_attribut}`.

in your case : `${syslog.hostname}`

I suggest you to look at expression language if you want to use routeOnAttribut processor :

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html

Comment: Thanks! I've tried using the expression ${syslog.hostname:contrains('one_of_my_source_ips')} using the route to matched if any strategy but I am not seeing any matches. Is there a way (using some processor) to extract the values of ${syslog.hostname} and write just those values to disk or a file so that I can create a list of the incoming source ip addresses?

Comment: you can use LogMessage processor for exemple: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage/ with ${syslog.hostname} , if it's just for debugging, you can look at attribut of flowfile wile they are in queue.